# popBackStackImmediate open onStart method on Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have a bottom bar with diferent tabs. When one is pressed a fragment should start. Im trying implement backStack on my project. The objective is, when i press a diferent tab, the fragment will be poped from backstack or created if does not exist.

```
void cretePeopleFrgament() {
    boolean fragmentPopped = fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate("Users", 0);

    if (!fragmentPopped) { //fragment not in back stack, create it.
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fraggy = new FragmentAllPeople();
        ft.addToBackStack("Users");
        ft.replace(R.id.conteiner, fraggy);
        ft.commit();
    }
    setDrawerEnabled(false);

}
```

with this im trying to evitate conections to server

```
 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    Http conections(...)
    }
```

the problem is that both one´s, popBackStackImmediate and Fragment fraggy = new FragmentAllPeople(); pass form the method on Start. How can i evitate these conections?

Comment: Im asking for help...if you can give me any document for learn something about that, i appreciate. If you cant. Thanks for your coment, but doesnt help anything.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to using a [ViewPager with Fragments (and tabs)](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/). The FragmentStatePagerAdapter will do the backstack popping automatically for you then.